# Responsive Navigation Menu with collapsing Menu bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, menubar

I developed a navigation menu which is responsive. How can I make the menu that when it is on a screen resolution max 480px not stacked under each other but gets hidden and shown like the below:
[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>

<div class="logo">
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100606210319/grooveshark/images/c/c2/Logo_Horizontal.jpg" alt="logo" /></a>
</div>

  <ul>
     <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
     <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Products</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Main Menu CSS*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);
#cssmenu {padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;}
#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {position: relative; z-index: 597; }
#cssmenu ul li { float: left; min-height: 1px; vertical-align: middle;}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default;}
#cssmenu ul ul {visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598;}
#cssmenu ul ul li {float: none;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {top: 0; left: auto; right: -99.5%; }
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul {bottom: 0; left: 0;}
#cssmenu ul ul {margin-top: 0; }
#cssmenu ul ul li {font-weight: normal;}
#cssmenu a { display: block; line-height: 1em; text-decoration: none; }

#cssmenu {
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

  #cssmenu > ul { *display: inline-block; }

  #cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
}

#cssmenu a {
    background: #333;
    color: #CBCBCB;
    padding: 0 20px; 
}
#cssmenu ul { text-transform: uppercase; }

    #cssmenu ul ul {
      border-top: 4px solid #1b9bff;
      text-transform: none;
      min-width: 190px; 
}
      #cssmenu ul ul a {
        background: #1b9bff;
        color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #0082e7;
        border-top: 0 none;
        line-height: 150%;
        padding: 16px 20px; 
}
      #cssmenu ul ul ul { border-top: 0 none; }

      #cssmenu ul ul li { position: relative }

#cssmenu > ul > li > a { line-height: 80px;  }

#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a { border-top: 1px solid #0082e7; }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a { background: #35a6ff; }

        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
          border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff; 
}
        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child:hover > a { border-radius: 0 0 0 3px; }

        #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
          content: '+';
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          right: 15px;
          margin-top: -8px;
}

 #cssmenu ul li:hover > a, #cssmenu ul li.active > a {
      background: #1b9bff;
      color: #FFF;
}
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
      content: '+';
      margin-left: 5px; 
}
    #cssmenu ul li.last ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 0; 
}
      #cssmenu ul li.last ul ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 99.5%;
}

.logo{
    margin-top:0px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20%;
    padding-right:10px;
  }

.logo img{
    width:200px;
    height:66px;

}

@Media screen and (max-width:480px) {  

#cssmenu ul li {      display: block ;    width: 100% ;  text-align:center; } 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a { line-height: 60px;  }
.content1{font-size:100%;}
}
}

@Media screen and (max-width:768px) {  
.logo{ margin-left:10%;}
}
```

Here you can also find a fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/uA4fL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically made ​​changes in the average query 480px,

see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uA4fL/6/

if not what you expect. regards

```
@Media screen and (max-width:480px) {  
    #cssmenu *:not{ float :left !important; width: 100%;padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important;}
    .logo{margin:0;padding:0}
    #cssmenu .logo > a{margin:0;padding:0}
#cssmenu ul li {    display: block ;    width: 100% ;  text-align:center; } 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a { line-height: 60px;  }
#cssmenu ul ul {
border-top: 4px solid #1b9bff;
text-transform: none;
width: 100%;
/* float: left; */
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {display:none;}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
border-top: 0 none;
visibility:visible;
display: block;
float: left;
clear: both;
position:relative;
right: 0;
}
        #cssmenu ul li.hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover{
            display:inline-block;
        }
.content1{font-size:100%;}
}
```

Comment: This is not showing the menu as shown in the wireframe above.